# How to get the list of all attributes of manytomanyfield related model?

Tags: django-rest-framework, serialization

How to get the list of attributes of a manytomanyfield related model from the other model?

Lets say, we have three models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Model2(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Model3(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    modelone=models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    modeltwo=models.ManyToManyField(Model2)
```

As you can see that Model3 has foreignkey relation to model1 and ManyTomanyField relation to model2.

Now, to define the serializer:

```
class Model1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Model1
        fields='__all__'

class Model2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Model2
        fields='__all__'

class Model3Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Model3
        fields='__all__'
```

Thus, the current serialized value of model3 is `{'id':1,'name':'abc','modelone':2,'modeltwo':[2,3]}`
What I want is:
`{'id':1,'name':'abc','modelone':2,'modeltwo':[2,3],'modeltwo_names':['pqr','xyz'],'modelone_name':'mno'}`

To have the name of modelone, we can add 
`modelone_name=serializers.CharField(source='modelone.name')`
But, I am not sure how to do it for ManyToManyField?

I tried doing:
`modeltwo_name=serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(source='modeltwo.name'))`
But, doing the above gave me the error:
`AssertionError: The`source`argument is not meaningful when applied to a`child=`field. Remove`source=`from the field declaration.`

Answer (score 0):

you can add `Model2Serialize` in `Model3Serializer` will have all related field that you need :

```
class Model3Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    modeltwo = Model2Serialize(many=True)
    modelone = Model1Serialize(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model=Model3
        fields='__all__'
```

the output will be something like :

```
{
 'id':1,
 'name':'abc',
 'modelone':{
          'id'=1,
          'name'='anyyyyy'
         },
 'modeltwo':[
         {
          'id' = 1,
          'name' = 'foo'
         },
         {
          'id' = 2,
          'name' = 'foo'
         }
       ]
}
```

here is doc [Nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).hope help.